# Twitter PHP API - Search by hashtag dont working

Tags: php, twitter

I need to get a lot of tweets with Twitter PHP API but when i make request it returns that no tweets found. When i looking for tweets but hashtag on site i see a lot of them.

```
$settings = array(
                'oauth_access_token' => "secret",
                'oauth_access_token_secret' => "secret",
                'consumer_key' => "secret",
                'consumer_secret' => "secret"
            );
            $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
            $getField = '?q=#ifiliveresult_type=recent';
            $requestMethod = 'GET';

            Yii::import('application.helpers.TwitterAPIExchange');
            $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
            echo $twitter->setGetfield($getField)
                ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                ->performRequest();
```

it returns me

```
completed_in: 0.005
count: 15
max_id: 527874293112512500
max_id_str: "527874293112512512"
query: "%23ifilive"
refresh_url: "?since_id=527874293112512512&q=%23ifilive&result_type=recent&include_entities=1"
since_id: 0
since_id_str: "0"
```

and empty statuses array.

Maybe twitter have some restrictions of something?

Comment: It's strange.. I have working hashtag grabber but it fails with your tag 'ifilive'.. maybe posting tweet with this tag will refresh some search index for api or so because it hasn't been used for few months. When I use different tag everything works fine.

Comment: are you escaping the "#" symbol? Or do the twitter library escapes for you automatically?

Comment: It escapes automatically

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue in the past. From the [Twitter dev site](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets):

> Please note that Twitter’s search service and, by extension, the
>   Search API is not meant to be an exhaustive source of Tweets. Not all
>   Tweets will be indexed or made available via the search interface.

Some older hashtags simply won't be returned in the search results.

/ü